# Hibernate mapping exception with join table

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, mapping

I've been facing a mapping exception I simply don't understand.
Here is the exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FKCA2E919A5E0752D:cim10_indicationgroup_indicator [indicatorId])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (cim10_indicationgroup [indicationGroupId,cim10Id])
```

The tables are as follows (notice already the discrepancy regarding the PK):

```
desc cim10_indicationgroup_indicator;
+-------------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                   | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| cim10_indicationgroupId | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| indicatorId             | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-------------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+

desc cim10_indicationgroup;
+-------------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                   | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| cim10_indicationGroupId | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| indicationGroupId       | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| cim10Id                 | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-------------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+

desc indicator;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| indicatorId | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| indicator   | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

On Hibernate side, entities stand as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cim10_indicationgroup")
@Immutable
public class Cim10IndicationGroupCouple {

   @Id
   @Column(name = "cim10_indicationGroupId")
   private Integer cim10IndicationGroupId;

   @Column(name = "indicationGroupId")
   private Integer indicationGroupId;

   @Column(name = "cim10Id")
   private Integer cim10Id;

   @ManyToMany
   @JoinTable(
      name = "cim10_indicationgroup_indicator",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "indicatorId")
   )
   private Set<Indicator> indicators;

   // getters, setters, equals/hashcode
```

And the referenced entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "indicator")
@Immutable
public class Indicator {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "indicatorId")
  private Integer id;

  @Column(name = "indicator")
  private String indicator;

   // getters, setters, equals/hashcode
```

As a bonus, here comes the metadata from the problematic join table:

```
SHOW KEYS FROM cim10_indicationgroup\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: cim10_indicationgroup
  Non_unique: 0
    Key_name: PRIMARY
Seq_in_index: 1
 Column_name: cim10_indicationGroupId
   Collation: A
 Cardinality: 10137
    Sub_part: NULL
      Packed: NULL
        Null:
  Index_type: BTREE
     Comment:
*************************** 2. row ***************************
       Table: cim10_indicationgroup
  Non_unique: 0
    Key_name: cim10_indicationGroup_pk
Seq_in_index: 1
 Column_name: cim10Id
   Collation: A
 Cardinality: 10137
    Sub_part: NULL
      Packed: NULL
        Null:
  Index_type: BTREE
     Comment:
*************************** 3. row ***************************
       Table: cim10_indicationgroup
  Non_unique: 0
    Key_name: cim10_indicationGroup_pk
Seq_in_index: 2
 Column_name: indicationGroupId
   Collation: A
 Cardinality: 10137
    Sub_part: NULL
      Packed: NULL
        Null:
  Index_type: BTREE
     Comment:
*************************** 4. row ***************************
       Table: cim10_indicationgroup
  Non_unique: 1
    Key_name: fk_cim10_indicationGroup_indicationGroup
Seq_in_index: 1
 Column_name: indicationGroupId
   Collation: A
 Cardinality: 633
    Sub_part: NULL
      Packed: NULL
        Null:
  Index_type: BTREE
     Comment:
```

Why is there a mapping exception at all?

Answer (score 1):

I think your `@ManyToMany` mapping is wrong. `joinColumn` specifies the column used to join the source entity ('Cim10IndicationGroupCouple') with join table, and `inverseJoinColumn` specifies the column used to join the target entity ('Indicator'). Try this

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
   name = "cim10_indicationgroup_indicator",
   joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "cim10_indicationgroupId")}, 
   inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="indicatorId")}
)
private Set<Indicator> indicators;
```

I agree that the exception is misleading, especially if this fixes it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out and let you know.

Comment: Still getting: "Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FKCA2E919AF72C81E8:cim10_indicationgroup_indicator [cim10_indicationgroupId])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (cim10_indicationgroup [indicationGroupId,cim10Id])"

Comment: Just ran into the same exception in my project. It was caused by two `@Id` annotations on different fields in entity (one was in parent class). Can you confirm there is nothing similar in your entities?

Comment: It used to be like this (2 @Id) but I first fixed it. Somehow, Hibernate  doesn't see this.